# Recompiling modded openssl for Android?

Tags: cryptography, android, openssl, reverse-engineering

"Reverse engineering its API? How? It uses a native library for encryption, it's *impossible* to decompile!" Some might say to lots of modern applications. But who needs to decompile? They couldn't have written a ~20kbyte library that *reinvents* cryptography all by itself.

I thought "strace might be useful if they also call external libraries..." but after seeing loads of `futex()` calls, I've decided to sit down and think about it. SSL... TLS... One standard. Openssl! That's it! And with a quick `frida-trace -U gadget -i "OPENSSL*"`, my theory was confirmed. The native libraries use openssl in the background.

Edit: I have already tried injecting Smali code before the native call, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648196/modifying-smali-files) but I don't really have much experience with it, and I just received a "failed to communicate with the server" error, and no logs in the logcat.

My question is: would it be possible to recompile openssl from [source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) and include some logging functions in it? If yes, then how? And also: will it help me in reverse engineering some apps? (Android arm64 is my target arch)

Comment: this is not a security question but a programming question

Comment: @schroeder I'm sorry, could you please move it to SO then?

Comment: You can already hook [on native functions with Frida](https://www.notsosecure.com/instrumenting-native-android-functions-using-frida/) and log stuff within the callback function. It does not really answer your question but that will be way easier than replacing their native library.

Comment: @swapgs I will have a look at it, thanks!